# Yii2 show hint on validation

Tags: validation, yii2, hint

Can I show hint in yii2 during validation? 
in my model I have:

```
    public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['content'], 'checkLastCommentDate', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'skipOnError' => false],
            ];
        }

   public function checkLastCommentDate($attribute)
    {
        if (true) {
           //can set hint here?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Model::addError method:

```
public function checkLastCommentDate($attribute)
{
    if (true) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Here is my hint');
    }
}
```

Comment: No,  yii2 have something like hint but I can't use it in validation. Maybe it shouldn't be in validation? I would like show hint only if $vat == 5